# When i run command npm install it is give error npm ERR cb() never called

Tags: laravel, npm

this type of error

> npm ERR! CB() never called!

I have already cleared clear npm cache
I have already run this command

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm package.lock.json yarn.lock
npm cache clear --force
npm install
```

> npm, WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2
>   at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1 npm ERR!
>   CB() never called!

Valid answer give for this error
and this command I run on my ubuntu server machine
node v6.17.1
npm  v3.10.10
already installed

```
npm run development
```

> npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run"
>   "developement" npm ERR! node v6.17.1 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
>
> npm ERR! missing script: development npm ERR! npm ERR! If you need
>   help, you may report this error at: npm ERR!
>   https://github.com/npm/npm/issues
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     /home/project_name/public_html/npm-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

- delete  all your npm cache file manually in %APPDATA%/Roaming/npm-cache.
- then run `npm cache clean --force`
- then append this in your `package.json`.
  please update the latest version of node and give that version below.

```
"engines": {
    "node": "14.17.0"
}
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

The part that says "cb() never called" looks like it's just a warning and probably isn't a big issue right now.

The error you are gettin below that seems to indicate that you have no "development" script defined under "scripts" in `package.json`. You probably want something that looks like this in `package.json`:

```
  6   "scripts": {
  7     "development": "node server.js",
  8   }
```

Although the script itself may vary based on how you have your development server setup

Comment: "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.co$

Comment: Do you get the same error when you copy/paste the script directly into the command prompt?

Comment: yes 
actually i didn't understand this problem
i have try all this solution

Comment: listen npm install successful but
when i run npm run dev command again it is give error

Comment: error look like :- ! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`

Comment: Failed at the @ development script 'cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js'.